# Change swiper object parameter

Tags: javascript, object, swiper.js

I am using swiper within a stencil component.

This is working great so far, however, I am encountering a problem when trying to change the parameters using the .params function when using an object like pagination.

This is the code I have:

```js
this.mySwiper.params.pagination.el = this.el.querySelector('.swiper-scrollbar');
this.mySwiper.params.pagination.type = 'progressbar';
```

However, it is not initializing the pagination. I am not sure this is the correct way to get into an object.

Comment: Has your swiper be initialised yet when you change these properties? Because I don't think you can change the pagination after init.

Comment: Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jr1w0Lb2/ When we declare the swiper we set init to false (which means we need to manually call `init()`